# Page not reloading upon hitting submit button

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

My website has a table of gymnasts created from a data.txt. Upon filling out the Add Gymnast form and hitting the submit button, I want the gymnast to be added to the table. However, when I hit the submit button, the data.txt file is updated, but I need to hit refresh to see the table updated. I don't know why this is happening since submit button should be doing an automatic refresh, so how do I fix this?

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="add">
    <div class = "subtitle">Basic Information</div>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value> 
            <input type="number" name="age" min="16" max="100" placeholder="Age" value>
            <input type="number" class = "heightField" name="feet" min="4" max="6" value>
            <span class = "heightLabel">ft</span>   
            <input type="number" class = "heightField" name="inches" min="0" max="11" value>
            <span class = "heightLabel">in</span>
    <button type = "submit" class = "addBtn" name = "add" value = "Add Gymnast">Add Gymnast</button>
</form>

//Write gymnast to file
function write_file($filename, $gymnast){
    $arr = array($gymnast->name, $gymnast->age, $gymnast->height, $gymnast->olympicYear, $gymnast->medalCount, $gymnast->image);
    $line = implode("\t", $arr);
    $line .= "\n";

    $file_pointer = fopen($filename, 'a' );
    if ( ! $file_pointer ) { 
        echo( 'error' ); 
        exit; 
    }
    $error = fputs($file_pointer,$line);
    fclose($file_pointer);
}
```

Let me know if you need to see other parts of my code. I didn't know what to include for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php where you write file at bottom of it include following code:

```php
header("Refresh:0");
```

This will reloads the page.

**ADDITION:**

If you want to redirect to another page use below code:

```php
header("Refresh:0; url=page2.php");
```

Replace **page2.php** with your custom page.